# Essential Prime Implicant with "don't care"

Tags: binary, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, karnaugh-map

How to count Prime Implicant/ate and Essential Prime Implicant/ate when I have don't care in my K-map?

For xample, for the following K-map, how many PI and EPI do I have?:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBmEV.png)

For Prime Implicant:

- If I can set all X to 1, then I have 1 PI
- If I can't consider Xs, then I have 4 PI

For Essential Prime Implicant:

- If I can set all X to 1, then I have 1 EPI
- If I can't consider Xs, then I have 4 EPI

Which would be the correct answer?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!